# Erasing and modifying elements in Boost MultiIndex Container

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use a Boost MultiIndex container in my simulation. My knowledge of C++ syntax is very weak, and I'm concerned I'm not properly removing an element from the container or deleting it from memory. I also need to modify elements, and I was hoping to confirm the syntax and basic philosophy here too.

```
// main.cpp
...
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
...
#include "Host.h" // class Host, all members private, using get fxns to access

using boost::multi_index_container;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

typedef multi_index_container<
  boost::shared_ptr< Host >,
  indexed_by< 
    hashed_unique< const_mem_fun<Host,int,&Host::getID> >
    //   ordered_non_unique< BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEM_FUN(Host,int,&Host::getAge) >
    > // end indexed_by
  > HostContainer;

typedef HostContainer::nth_index<0>::type HostsByID;

int main() {
   ...
   HostContainer allHosts;
   Host * newHostPtr;
   newHostPtr = new Host( t, DOB, idCtr, 0, currentEvents );
   allHosts.insert( boost::shared_ptr<Host>(newHostPtr) );
   // allHosts gets filled up

   int randomHostID = 4;
   int newAge = 50;
   modifyHost( randomHostID, allHosts, newAge );
   killHost( randomHostID, allHosts );
}

void killHost( int id, HostContainer & hmap ){
  HostsByID::iterator it = hmap.find( id );
  cout << "Found host id " << (*it)->getID() << "Attempting to kill. hmap.size() before is " << hmap.size() << " and ";
  hmap.erase( it ); // Is this really erasing (freeing from mem) the underlying Host object?
  cout << hmap.size() << " after." << endl;
}

void modifyHost( int id, HostContainer & hmap, int newAge ){
  HostsByID::iterator it = hmap.find( id );
  (*it) -> setAge( newAge ); // Not actually the "modify" function for MultiIndex...
}
```

My questions are

1. In the MultiIndex container `allHosts` of shared_ptrs to `Host` objects, is calling `allHosts.erase( it )` on an iterator to the object's shared_ptr enough to delete the object permanently and free it from memory? It appears to be removing the shared_ptr from the container.
2. The `allhosts` container currently has one functioning index that relies on the host's ID. If I introduce an ordered second index that calls on a member function (Host::getAge()), where the age changes over the course of the simulation, is the index always going to be updated when I refer to it?
3. What is the difference between using the MultiIndex's modify to modify the age of the underlying object versus the approach I show above?
4. I'm vaguely confused about what is assumed/required to be constant in MultiIndex.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

Here's my attempt to get the `modify` syntax working, based on what I see in a related Boost [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating).

```
struct update_age {
  update_age():(){} // have no idea what this really does... elicits error
  void operator() (boost::shared_ptr<Host> ptr) {
    ptr->incrementAge(); // incrementAge() is a member function of class Host
  }
};
```

and then in `modifyHost`, I'd have `hmap.modify(it,update_age)`. Even if by some miracle this turns out to be right, I'd love some kind of explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`shared_ptr` will remove actual `Host` object in its destructor (if there is no other instances of `shared_ptr`). All objects in MultiIndex are considered constant. To modify the object you should use method [`modify`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#modify) of MultiIndex. In that case indexes will be updates if necessary.

You could use the following functor to change `age` field:

```
  struct change_age
  {
    change_age(int age) : age_(age) {}    
    void operator()(boost::shared_ptr<Host> h) // shared_ptr !!!
    {
      h->age = age_;
    }

  private:
    int age_;
  };
```

Then use it as follows:

```
  testHosts.modify( it, Host::change_age( 22 ) ); // set age to 22
```

Comment: Thanks again. Even after studying your link, I'm still having trouble with the modify syntax. Using hmap.modify(it,incrementAge()), with Host::incrementAge(), causes an out-of-scope error. I see some examples using structs (when the container elements are the objects themselves) but can't follow why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, Kirill--that's very useful. (I have other member functions that take inputs, and that I will need to invoke with modify().) I'm still confused about what to do when I'm just trying to call a member function that doesn't take inputs, though--is my edited code above right?

Comment: You should pass functor object to a `modify` function. In your case it will look like `hmap.modify( it, update_age() )`.

Comment: The struct I proposed above yields the following compiler errors: "main.cpp:76: error: anachronistic old-style base class initializer
main.cpp:76: error: unnamed initializer for ‘update_age’, which has no base classes"

Comment: I commented out the stupid line (update_age():(){} ), and everything looks like it's working!